# bash error !{P: event not found

Tags: bash, zfs

What is wrong with this command sequence:

```
stephen@stephen:~$ RETENTION=3
stephen@stephen:~$ echo $RETENTION
3
stephen@stephen:~$ SNAP=bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_7pdn8o@autozsys_
stephen@stephen:~$ sudo zfs list -t snapshot -o name | grep ^$SNAP | sed -n -e :a -e "1,${RETENTION}!{P;N;D;};N;ba" | xargs -n 1 echo zfs destroy -nprd
bash: !{P: event not found
```

?

The intent here is to delete all but the three most recent snapshots. What should be there instead of !{P to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes allow bash to treat `!` as a [shell history event designator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html). If you want to prevent that, but still allow expansion of shell variable `${RETENTION}`, you can switch from double quotes to single quotes after the variable:

```
"1,${RETENTION}"'!{P;N;D;};N;ba'
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks :)